# Get Window ID from xcb using a class or name

Tags: qt, xcb

I want to use Qt's `QWindow::fromWinID` function to draw widgets onto an external window (hopefully this will work).

Unfortunately, I need to draw on a window which has a certain name/class (I can show it using xwininfo and xprop). The only code I can find to do this is inside the source of xwininfo and xprop, but it seems like a bunch of unnecessary code to do a simple thing: find the window with a certain property equal to some string, and return its window ID for Qt to use. Unfortunately, I'm very badly versed in XCB, and wouldn't know how to start.

How can I do this without 200 lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only code I can find to do this is inside the source of xwininfo and xprop

Which really is a great resource, alongside with xdotool.

> find the window with a certain property equal to some string

Yeah, but there's no X11 built-in that does this, which is why those tools go that way. Then there's things to consider like reparenting and non-reparenting window managers, i.e., whether or not you need to descend into the client window and so on.

I'm afraid there's no much easier way. Low-level X programming, whether with Xlib or XCB, just brings some verbosity.

One thing you could consider is using the library extracted from (and used by) `xdotool`, called `libxdo`. It would offer this functionality for you in `xdo_search_windows`. The library uses (and therefore pulls in) Xlib rather than XCB, though.

Here's a sample program you can compile with `gcc -lxdo test.c`:

```
#include <xdo.h>

int main() {
    xdo_t *xdo = xdo_new(NULL);
    xdo_enter_text_window(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, "A", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on libxdo. It seems though, I can't link with it (or at least the symbols `nm` tells me it defines remain undefined after I link with it... I do have `/usr/lib/libxdo.so` on my system (and the linker can find the file), but I still get an undefined reference. ANy idea why this might be?

Comment: @rubenvb I've edited my answer with a sample program and compile instructions. This works for me.

Comment: It seems I need to add extern "C" over the xdo.h include or I get unresolved symbols. Thanks for the help!